# HQL Error: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, hql

I recently ran into a problem I can't get a grip on. When executing a query from my grails app I get the following exception:

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode 
 +-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'MAX'
 |  \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
 |     +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'distance_weight' {originalText=distance_weight}
 |     \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
 |        +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=latitude, expectedType=null}
 |        +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=longitude, expectedType=null}
 |        +-[DOT] DotNode: 'place3_.location_latitude' {propertyName=latitude,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=location.latitude,path=p.location.latitude,tableAlias=place3_,className=gibbons5.l10n.Place,classAlias=p}
...
```

The query I'm trying to execute looks like this (latitude and longitude are passed to the executeQuery call):

```
SELECT MAX(distance_weight(:latitude, :longitude, p.location.latitude, p.location.longitude)) AS distance_weight, MIN(distance(:latitude, :longitude, p.location.latitude, p.location.longitude)) AS distance 
FROM Activity AS a
LEFT JOIN a.events AS e
LEFT JOIN e.place AS p
```

Where distance and distance_weight are stored functions within the mysql database to calculate the distance between to locations and give them a weight:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `distance`(deg_lat1 FLOAT, deg_lng1 FLOAT, deg_lat2 FLOAT, deg_lng2 FLOAT) RETURNS FLOAT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
...
```

and

```
CREATE FUNCTION `distance_weight`(deg_lat1 FLOAT, deg_lng1 FLOAT, deg_lat2 FLOAT, deg_lng2 FLOAT) RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
...
```

Every Activity can have multiple Events, which each have their own place with a location (lat/long).

What am I doing w!rong? Every idea is highly appreciated!!